# How to build a custom Firebase registration confirmation / validation / email reset

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, sparkpost

This is driving me completely bonkers.
I cant use the firebase email system to notify the user about account validation email, email reset or email change becasue I cant change the language or template. So I started using Sparkpost. 
I already built most of its functionality, but I found that I cant obtaing the confirmation code for this actions.

Is there a way to use any of this functionalities without using the email system? Can I in any way obtain the "code" needed to execute:

```
[confirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword)][3]
[checkActionCode(code)][2]
[applyActionCode(code)][1]
```

If I can in any way obtain this code I could use a mix of sparkpost mail system and angular page to validate user or change password on my ionic app. Or I could make a node endpoint to do this operations.

I really need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the verification code through a public API.

But you *can* verify user accounts in your server-side code directly (without calling `checkActionCode`/`applyActionCode`) by using the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js.

From the [documentation on updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user):

> The `updateUser()` method allows you to modify an existing user's data. It accepts a `uid` for the user to update as well as an object containing the `UserRecord` properties to update:
>
> ```
> admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
>   email: "modifiedUser@example.com",
>   emailVerified: true,
>   password: "newPassword",
>   displayName: "Jane Doe",
>   photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
>   disabled: true
> })
>   .then(function(userRecord) {
>     console.log("Successfully updated user", userRecord.toJSON());
>   })
>   .catch(function(error) {
>     console.log("Error updating user:", error);
>   });
> ```

With this you can build your own verification mechanism and then simply update the user's status once you're done.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this actually helps me a lot, because now I can make a document and store my own validation key in order to activate the account.
About reset, I just learned that that is the only email template I can modify.
Thanks.

Comment: I ended creating a Lambda service, where I uploaded de Admin Node package, Now I can manage users from my serverless app.
Thanks its working.

Comment: That sounds pretty cool Pablo! If you feel like writing your own answer or a blog post about it, I'm quite sure it'd be useful to more people.